# ActiveXObject("Shell.Application") - how to pass arguments with spaces?

Tags: asp.net, activex, shellexecute

I run exe from my asp.net with JavaScript using ActiveXObject. It runs successfully, except parameters:

```
function CallEXE() {
  var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
  var prog = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\myCustom.exe";                 
  oShell.ShellExecute(prog,"customer name fullname","","open","1");
}
```

Example, I pass that like parameters,[1] customer name,[2] fullname, but after space character, Javascript perceive different parameter.

How can I fix?

Comment: I hope you're working on an intranet application...

Comment: yes,i working intranet application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes the 2nd parameter to be a string that represents *all* the arguments and processes these using normal shell processing rules: spaces and quotes, in particular.

```
oShell.ShellExecute(prog,"customer name fullname",...)
```

In this case the 3 parameters that are passed are `customer`, `name`, `fullname`

<del>`oShell.ShellExecute(prog,"customer 'a name with spaces' fullname",...)`</del>

As corrected/noted by Remy Lebeau - TeamB, double-quotes can be used to defined argument boundaries:

```
oShell.ShellExecute(prog,'customer "a name with spaces" fullname',...)
```

In this case the 3 parameters that are passed are `customer`, `a name with spaces`, `fullname`

That is, think of how you would call `myCustom.exe` from the command-prompt. It's the same thing when using `ShellExecute`.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks @pst,but it still different parameter :)

Comment: @engcmreng Aww :( What do you end up with?

Comment: Wrap the parameter value with spaces using double-quotes instead of single-quotes, eg: `oShell.ShellExecute(prog, "customer \"a name with spaces\" fullname",...)` or `oShell.ShellExecute(prog, 'customer "a name with spaces" fullname',...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your spaces with a backslash.  The cmd.exe `cd` command does this, maybe you'll get lucky and it'll work here as well...

```
oShell.ShellExecute(prog,"customer a\ name\ with\ spaces fullname", ...)
```